# Endless loop stops checking IF functions after first one is correct - Python, Blockchain transactions

Tags: python, list, blockchain, web3py

I am looking more specifically at Web3, in the aim of creating a script to send off blockchain transactions four times - three times before the intended 'starting block', and then finally sending one when it reaches the starting block. Firstly, i produced the first code, my thinking behind this is that it checks the latest_block every 0.1 seconds, in turn running thorough the if statements, and if the latest_block is either of the 4 defined variables, it will run the function "run_wallets". However, from trialling it, it works correctly for the first block which it encounters (the three_before variable) and then stops checking the statements once it has found one 'True' statement.

```
starting_block = 10079310
one_before = 10079309
two_before = 10079308
three_before = 10079307


def update():
    while True:

        time.sleep(0.1)
        latest_block = web3.eth.blockNumber
        print(latest_block)

        if latest_block == three_before:
            run_wallets()

        elif latest_block == two_before:
            run_wallets()

        elif latest_block == one_before:
            run_wallets()

        elif latest_block == starting_block:
            run_wallets()

update()
```

This is understandable as the loop will stop once it has a 'true' statement. I therefore tried to create a list, and make a loop that will keep running until the list is empty. So this time, once the first IF statement was true, it would remove the variable from the list so that it is no longer in the list, and therefore will run the wallets on the other 3 blocks until the list is empty. I had a go and produced the following, which still isn't working..

```
starting_block = 10079310
one_before = 10079309
two_before = 10079308
three_before = 10079307


list = [ three_before, two_before, one_before, starting_block ]

def update():
      while list:

        time.sleep(0.1)
        latest_block = web3.eth.blockNumber
        print(latest_block)

        if latest_block in list:
            run_wallets()
            list.remove(three_before)

        if latest_block in list:
            run_wallets()
            list.remove(two_before)

        if latest_block in list:
            run_wallets()
            list.remove(one_before)

        if latest_block in list:
            run_wallets()
            list.remove(starting_block)

update()
```

Therefore overall, can someone show me what I'm doing wrong and kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: In both examples you omit the parentheses on `run_wallets` in the first if-clause, meaning the function isn't called.

Comment: In your second snippet your first if will remain true even after you remove `three_before`.Wben `latest_block`equals `starting_block` all four if-statements will evaluate as true.